# Is it Bad Practice to Apply CSS Based on the Style Attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was working on a project, and I needed to tell a background image to center, when I got an idea. What if I used a selector that found if `style="background-image: url()"` was present and added the necessary code to center the image. The idea of adding CSS based on the style attribute seems like really bad practice, but when I thought about it more, maybe it could be used in a reset file. Since the selector is not that specific it should be easily overwritten, and it allows the default background style for all divs with `style="background-image: url()"` to be changed.

I am not sure how practical this is, but is this something that is ever done? Are there any issues I am overseeing that this could cause? Maybe this is not realistic, but I thought it was interesting enough to start a discussion on. See example code below...

```css
div{
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

[style*=background-image]{
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhYGF.png)"></div>
```

Comment: of course it is dangerous!!

Comment: This won't work if the background image is specified in a rule in a CSS file. it's probably also not necessary. You can specify global defaults for `background-size` etc. and they will simply have no effect if there's no background image.

Comment: Yeah that is one of the reasons why I don't think it's practical. Still interesting though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on your project. Will all your `<div>`s only be used for this purpose? and will all your background images be centered? If so, then maybe it's fine, but if you think you'll be overwriting them for other elements in your project then it might cause issues down the road as you develop your application.

Why don't you try something like this:

```
<div class="center-image" style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhYGF.png')"></div>

.center-image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

or if you have multiple ones in one section:

```
<div class="center-image-wrapper">
   <div style="background-image: url(path-to-img1)"></div>
   <div style="background-image: url(path-to-img2)"></div>
   <div style="background-image: url(path-to-img3)"></div>
</div>

.center-image-wrapper > div {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
}
```

Also side note that you don't need to apply `display:block` to a div. div is already a block element.

Comment: Yeah in reality this is how I wound up doing it, but I was curious how useful this other method was because I have never seen it done before.

Answer (score 0):

Give a class to the div like `<div class="myclass">` and then apply styling like this:

```
.myclass [style*=background-image]
```